# Mounted USB Drive with bind mount in container, capacity showing less than drive contains

Tags: usb-drive, lxc, container

I have a 2TB SSD connected to my host device (Proxmox) and am passing it through to a container running Ubuntu.

In my Proxmox host, I can see the full drive:
[Drive image in host showing 2TB](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J2QGd.jpg)

I have the drive mounted into my container via the conf file after mounting the drive in my host from sda1 to /mnt/USBShare:

```
mp0: /mnt/USBShare,mp=/mnt/USBShare
```

When I check the drive in my container, I get a drive of 94G and not 2T.:

```
root@channels:/mnt/USBShare# df -h /mnt/USBShare
Filesystem            Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/mapper/pve-root   94G   22G   68G  25% /mnt/USBShare
```

I also started a Ubuntu VM to check how the drive would show up there since it's directly accessible, and there I see even less capacity:

```
root@ubuntu:/mnt/USBShare# df -H
Filesystem            Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/sda1              2.2G  1.8G  373M 83% /
```

Any idea what's causing the discrepancies and lack of full access to the drive storage?  And what can be done to access the full capacity in my container especially?

Thanks!